# Querying Entity with many to many relationship returning null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, automapper

In my events app, an Event can have many organizers and an organizer can organize many events. This is the `AppUser` Entity (this is what the organizers are):

```
public class AppUser
    {      
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime LastActive { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public string Location { get; set; } 
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Occupation { get; set; }
        public UserPhoto Photo { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; } 
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; } 
        public ICollection<UserLike> LikedByUsers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserLike> LikedUsers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Event> CreatedEvents { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserEvents> OrganisedEvents { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EventUsers> AttendingEvents { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the `Event`Entity:

```
public class Event
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public AppUser Creator { get; set; }
        public int CreatorId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MainPhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserEvents> Organisers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EventUsers> Attendees { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EventPhoto> Photos { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the join Entity I have created called `UserEvents`:

```
public class UserEvents
    {
        public AppUser Organiser { get; set; }
        public int OrganiserId { get; set; }
        public Event Event { get; set; }
        public int EventId { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the end point in my `EventsController` which adds the `Organiser` (British spelling!) to the existing event:

```
[HttpPut("add-organiser/{eventId}/{organiserId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> addOrganiser(int eventId, int organiserId)    
    {
        var existingEvent = await _eventsRepository.GetEventByIdAsync(eventId);
        var organiser = await _userRepository.GetUserByIdAsync(organiserId);
        var userEvent = new UserEvents {
            OrganiserId = organiserId,
            Organiser = organiser,
            EventId = eventId,
            Event = existingEvent
        };
        existingEvent.Organisers = existingEvent.Organisers ?? new List<UserEvents>();
        existingEvent.Organisers.Add(userEvent);
        if(await _eventsRepository.SaveAllAsync()) return Ok();
        return BadRequest("Failed to add organiser");
    }
```

I won't show the `GetEventByIdAsync` and `GetUserByIdAsync` methods in my repository's as this part of the code works correctly, I just wanted to give some context. I've ran the debugger when adding the `UserEvent` above and the correct `Event` and `AppUser` are added to the `Organisers` list above.

The problem I am having is when trying to query the database and retrieve the events, the organizers are being retrieved but the `UserName` is set to Null and the `Id`. Here is the `GetAllEvents` method from the `EventsController`:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EventDto>>> GetAllEvents()
        {
            var events = await _eventsRepository.GetEventsAsync();
            return Ok(events);
        }
```

This is the `GetEventsAsync` method from the `_eventsRepository`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<EventDto>> GetEventsAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Events
            .Include(e => e.Creator)
            .Include(e => e.Photos)
            .Include(e => e.Organisers)
            .ThenInclude(e => e.Organiser)
            .ProjectTo<EventDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .ToListAsync();
        }
```

As you can see above, the `Event` Entities are mapped to an `EventDto` using automapper. Here is the `EventDto`:

```
public class EventDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string MainPhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PhotoDto> Photos { get; set; }
        public MemberDto Creator { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MemberDto> Organisers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MemberDto> Attendees { get; set; }        
    }
```

The `Organisers` here are of type `MemberDto`. Here is the `MemberDto` class:

```
public class MemberDto
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
            public DateTime LastActive { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
            public string Location { get; set; } 
            public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
            public string Occupation { get; set; }
            public PhotoDto Photo { get; set; }

        }
```

Here is the relevant part of my AutoMapper configuration:

```
public AutoMapperProfile() {
     CreateMap<AppUser, MemberDto>();
     CreateMap<Event, EventDto>();
}
```

Here is the relevant part of the output from PostMan when using the `GetAllEvents` end point:

[image]

As you can see, it is retrieving the organizers but the `Id`'s are set to 0 and the `UserName`'s are `null`.

Sorry, I know this is a long post but I'm not sure which part of this process is going wrong. I would expect the `Organisers` to automatically be mapped to `MemberDto`'s by AutoMapper but it appears that something is failing with this mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to this resolve this by adding some extra configuration into AutoMapper:

```
CreateMap<Event, EventDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Organisers, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Organisers.Select(Organisers => Organisers.Organiser)));
```